# get a dynamic id from an iframe in an iframe

Tags: javascript, node.js, iframe

I am actually doing a tricky task, I have to create pack of resource(which are pages on the website), to do so I use iframe to display the content of the pages.  But I can have multiples Iframes in one Iframe.

And I want to pass some style on those iframe in iframe, so i have to target them.

I have a special node id for each pages that allow me to return only the body.

So my question is how do I get  to target the id of my iframe in my iframe which I tried to do with that line `var get_iframe_inside = search_inside.getElementsByTagName("iframe".id);` to then modify it's style.

I know that I am not using the right way for this line, but I have been scratching my head all this morning and can't find a way.

```
    function test(id){
        var iframe = window.parent.document.getElementById(id); //select my first iframe
        get_iframe_inside(id); //call my function to get the iframe in the iframe
        function get_iframe_inside (id){
            var search_inside = (iframe.contentDocument) ?iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
//My goal is then to modify some properties
            var get_iframe_inside = search_inside.getElementsByTagName("iframe".id); 
            $(get_iframe_inside).css({'padding':'0px 50px', 'background-color':'#cecece'});
        }
        
   }
```

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/) is looking for `<iframeID>` that is why it does not work not name attribute.

Comment: @epascarello i know that it doesn't work i just don't see how to make it work :/ i have tried `getElementsByTagName("iframe".id)` and `getElementById(id)` which return the previous id, I can't access the right id :/

Comment: well you are passing in the same id so not sure how it would use a different one....

Comment: Well I am a beginner, I am actualy aware that i don't pass the right id, it's actualy my question, how do i get to target that second id?

Comment: Do you know the new id? You have one id of the main iframe, do you know the id of the second one. If yes, seems like you should be passing in id1 and id2.  If you do not know the second id, than you should be selecting it by just the iframe element and any other meta data that you may know. It is really unclear what you have to work with in your question.

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, the id of the iframes correspond at the node (special id from the CMS) of the page called, so yeah it changes whenever it's a new page displayed in iframe.

Comment: `var  get_iframe_inside = search_inside.getElementsByTagName('iframe');` when i target by tag it return `HTMLCollection(2) [iframe, iframe#20223, 20223: undefined]` in my console.log

Answer (score 0):

Well it was kind of trivial my code was nearly working i just didn't tought at how to get thoses ids.
i just had to get them by tag and after that to do an iteration with for.

```
       var get_iframe_inside = search_inside.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < get_iframe_inside.length; i++){
        get_iframe_inside[i].style.padding='0px 50px';
```